# Como manter a rotação das imagens, mesmo com hover do mouse?

Tags: jquery

Minhas imagens da tela principal do site mudam após 5 segundos usando efeito fade, mas ao pararmos o mouse sobre a tela, elas param de rotacionar.

Segue trecho do código:

```
<li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="7"
  data-masterspeed="2000" data-thumb="img/backgrounds/bg-1.jpg"
  data-delay="10000" data-saveperformance="on"
  data-title="Viagens tornam-se inesquecíveis">
<img src="img/backgrounds/bg-1.jpg" alt="slidebg1"
  data-bgposition="center top" data-bgfit="cover"
  data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">
<!-- Home Heading -->
```

Como faço isso?

Comment: Boa pergunta. Como é que você implementa esse rodízio de imagens? Usando algum componente pronto?

Comment: O [_slider responsivo_ "Revolution"](http://www.orbis-ingenieria.com/code/documentation/documentation.html), então.

Answer (score 3):

A página usa um componente chamado ["Revolution Responsive jQuery Slider"](http://www.orbis-ingenieria.com/code/documentation/documentation.html). Segundo a documentação, existe um [parâmetro de inicialização](http://www.orbis-ingenieria.com/code/documentation/documentation.html#!/layout) chamado `onHoverStop` responsável por parar o temporizador (que muda as imagens) quando o ponteiro do mouse está sobre a imagem. Os valores válidos para esse parâmetro são `on` (padrão) e `off`.

Sendo assim, passe na chamada do construtor do `.Revolution({})` o par `onHoverStop: off,`, e o seu problema deve se resolver.

Comment: Na mosca,Wtrmute...

Rapaz, deu certinho, óh...

Agradeço muito, você me deu uma grande força. Problema RESOLVIDO!!!